# Parsing XML from URL using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, url, simplexml

I'm trying to echo the XML content at this URL but I'm having difficulty. Here's what I have so far:

```
$url = "GetVideosServlet?queryId=1";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$value = (string) $xml->results->item[0]->id;

echo $value;
```

I keep getting the error that I'm trying to get the property of a non-object. But I was under the impression simplexml_load_file converts my XML string INTO an object??

If anyone could show me how to echo out any of the content, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: That means `$xml` didn't get turned into an object. If it's [`false`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php), it didn't work.

Comment: but when I use print_r($xml), I SEE an object??

Comment: What does it give? (As in, put that in the question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just miss a tag which is `query`,
try:

```
$value = (string) $xml->query->results->item[0]->id;
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are debugging [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) are very handy! for example in this case if you dumped the $xml right after loading it you would have noticed that you missed out the SimpleXMLElement Object query.

```
$url = "http://176.34.224.80/REMPADRecSys/GetVideosServlet?queryId=1";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
```

Would give you the output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [query] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [results] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [item] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [id] => GZ7w39jpqwo
                                    [rank] => 1
                                    [explanation] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a massa lectus, sed convallis sapien. Curabitur sem mauris, ullamcorper ut. 
                                )
```

and so the correct reference would have been `$xml->query->results->item[0]->id;` like @Lake mentioned. Happy debugging.

Comment: Whoa...did you do that by echoing <pre> first? ...how does this work!?

Comment: yeh. It is really helpful. Check out [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) <pre> tag basically just preserves the line breaks and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode('http://176.34.224.80/REMPADRecSys/GetVideosServlet?queryId=1'));
```

try this.