# Curl GET returns different format than the browser

Tags: php, xml, curl

I call a curl GET ,and it returns a string not in XML format, if I call it from the browser it comes as an XML format.

I need the string to be in an xml format this is the curl call

```
$conn2 = curl_init("https://www.mysite.com/api/users?id=user&account=account&password=pw");
curl_setopt($conn2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($conn2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$result = curl_exec($conn2);

$xml =simplexml_load_string($result);
$oldCredit=$xml->credit;

dpm ($result);
```

Comment: Do you need to use curl to get the contents from the Url??? check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292475/parsing-xml-from-url-using-simplexml

Comment: Yes I have to use curl

Comment: Then its probably a user and password issue in you URL as you are using a web service. Check this solution if it helps --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662014/php-curl-http-get-xml-format

Comment: it cant be user and pw issue as I am getting the result from the api, but it doesn't come in XML format, if I call it from the browser it does come as XML Thanks

Comment: I changed the link in my comment so click it again, if you check it the person had the same issue as you. Browser Ok, Curl Not.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution could be adding these 2 line before you call `curl_exec()`

```
curl_setopt($conn2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($conn2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

You can read explanations of these and other options on [php.net site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Otherwise, you would have to install SSL, or make sure you have one already installed, and point your curl to it:

```
curl_setopt($conn2, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:/path-to-your-certs/cert.pem');
```

Reference: http://blog.josephwilk.net/snippets/curl-and-certificates-with-windows-php.html

Also: IT IS **BAD** to pass user info and credentials via url like that.